# jwt sign ( I need to get token , but I get underfined)

Tags: jwt

```
export async function createJwt(userEntity: any) {
    let value = await jsonwebtoken.sign({
        telephoneNumber: userEntity.telephoneNumber
    }, process.env.SECRET_KEY_FOR_JWT, {
        expiresIn: '2h'
    }, (err, token) => {
        if (err) throw err
        else {
            return token
        }
    });
//underfined
console.log(value
}
```

I can't get value.Why is it happens? Should I use promise or how can I get it?

Comment: Try to move the line console.log to be above `return token`, That is an async function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the let value inside the function? You cannot do that. It is out of scope.

If you do something like

```
const value = await createJwt(userEntity)
console.log(value)
```

or

```
consol.log(await createJwt(userEntity))
```

it should work.